# Network kBit/s drops to 0 intermittently

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I am streaming live video to a server on my PC, now and again the video stream would freeze. When looking at the output from `nload` the network speed seems to drop to `0kBit/s` for a second and then continues as normal. I'm on a wired connection in an enterprise setting and this seems to be an intermittent problem - could it be due to excessive network activity?

The streaming device is wireless that connects to a router which is connected to the same wired network as my PC.

EDIT: After running `tcpdump -w wowza.pcap dst 193.61.148.73 and tcp port 1935`

gave the following output:

Command - `tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r wowza.pcap`

```
reading from file wowza.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
14:27:21.575047 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfb0 4000 3f06 b05d c13d 9480  E.....@.?..].=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 69a0 cd35 0686  .=.I.o..<Ai..5..
    0x0020:  8018 05cd 7a82 0000 0101 080a 0000 74f6  ....z.........t.
    0x0030:  14c7 9412 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3736 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.76..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:21.578211 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfb1 4000 3f06 b0cd c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6a11 cd35 078d  .=.I.o..<Aj..5..
    0x0020:  8010 05de 89d8 0000 0101 080a 0000 74f6  ..............t.
    0x0030:  14c7 99f0                                ....
14:27:27.589620 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfb2 4000 3f06 b05b c13d 9480  E.....@.?..[.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6a11 cd35 078d  .=.I.o..<Aj..5..
    0x0020:  8018 05de 7019 0000 0101 080a 0000 77f7  ....p.........w.
    0x0030:  14c7 99f0 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3737 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.77..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:27.605648 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfb3 4000 3f06 b0cb c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6a82 cd35 0894  .=.I.o..<Aj..5..
    0x0020:  8010 05ee 7f6f 0000 0101 080a 0000 77f8  .....o........w.
    0x0030:  14c7 9fcf                                ....
14:27:33.601614 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfb4 4000 3f06 b059 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..Y.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6a82 cd35 0894  .=.I.o..<Aj..5..
    0x0020:  8018 05ee 65af 0000 0101 080a 0000 7af9  ....e.........z.
    0x0030:  14c7 9fcf 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3738 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.78..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:33.605189 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfb5 4000 3f06 b0c9 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6af3 cd35 099b  .=.I.o..<Aj..5..
    0x0020:  8010 05ff 7505 0000 0101 080a 0000 7af9  ....u.........z.
    0x0030:  14c7 a5af                                ....
14:27:39.626903 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfb6 4000 3f06 b057 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..W.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6af3 cd35 099b  .=.I.o..<Aj..5..
    0x0020:  8018 05ff 5b43 0000 0101 080a 0000 7dfb  ....[C........}.
    0x0030:  14c7 a5af 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3739 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.79..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:39.634879 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfb7 4000 3f06 b0c7 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6b64 cd35 0aa2  .=.I.o..<Akd.5..
    0x0020:  8010 0610 6a96 0000 0101 080a 0000 7dfd  ....j.........}.
    0x0030:  14c7 ab91                                ....
14:27:46.262184 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfb8 4000 3f06 b055 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..U.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6b64 cd35 0aa2  .=.I.o..<Akd.5..
    0x0020:  8018 0610 4fde 0000 0101 080a 0000 80fe  ....O...........
    0x0030:  14c7 ab91 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3830 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.80..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:46.664990 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfb9 4000 3f06 b054 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..T.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6b64 cd35 0aa2  .=.I.o..<Akd.5..
    0x0020:  8018 0610 4fc0 0000 0101 080a 0000 811c  ....O...........
    0x0030:  14c7 ab91 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3830 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.80..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:48.465048 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfba 4000 3f06 b0c4 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6bd5 cd35 0ba9  .=.I.o..<Ak..5..
    0x0020:  8010 0621 5f3d 0000 0101 080a 0000 8152  ...!_=.........R
    0x0030:  14c7 b20c                                ....
14:27:48.788570 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 dfbb 4000 3f06 b0b7 c13d 9480  E..@..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6bd5 cd35 0ba9  .=.I.o..<Ak..5..
    0x0020:  b010 0621 7823 0000 0101 080a 0000 816a  ...!x#.........j
    0x0030:  14c7 b240 0101 050a cd35 0aa2 cd35 0ba9  ...@.....5...5..
14:27:49.282536 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 dfbc 4000 3f06 b0b6 c13d 9480  E..@..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6bd5 cd35 0ba9  .=.I.o..<Ak..5..
    0x0020:  b010 0621 7787 0000 0101 080a 0000 819e  ...!w...........
    0x0030:  14c7 b2a8 0101 050a cd35 0aa2 cd35 0ba9  .........5...5..
14:27:50.980889 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 dfbd 4000 3f06 b0b5 c13d 9480  E..@..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6bd5 cd35 0ba9  .=.I.o..<Ak..5..
    0x0020:  b010 0621 7629 0000 0101 080a 0000 822c  ...!v).........,
    0x0030:  14c7 b378 0101 050a cd35 0aa2 cd35 0ba9  ...x.....5...5..
14:27:54.452894 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfbe 4000 3f06 b04f c13d 9480  E.....@.?..O.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6bd5 cd35 0ba9  .=.I.o..<Ak..5..
    0x0020:  8018 0621 4318 0000 0101 080a 0000 8453  ...!C..........S
    0x0030:  14c7 b378 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ...xOPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3831 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.81..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:54.454300 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfbf 4000 3f06 b04e c13d 9480  E.....@.?..N.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6bd5 cd35 0ba9  .=.I.o..<Ak..5..
    0x0020:  8018 0621 42b6 0000 0101 080a 0000 84b5  ...!B...........
    0x0030:  14c7 b378 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ...xOPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3831 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.81..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:27:55.546103 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfc0 4000 3f06 b0be c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6c46 cd35 0cb0  .=.I.o..<AlF.5..
    0x0020:  8010 0631 51a1 0000 0101 080a 0000 8567  ...1Q..........g
    0x0030:  14c7 ba0b                                ....
14:28:04.540998 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfc1 4000 3f06 b04c c13d 9480  E.....@.?..L.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6c46 cd35 0cb0  .=.I.o..<AlF.5..
    0x0020:  8018 0631 36e5 0000 0101 080a 0000 8869  ...16..........i
    0x0030:  14c7 ba0c 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3832 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.82..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:28:05.651839 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfc2 4000 3f06 b04b c13d 9480  E.....@.?..K.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6c46 cd35 0cb0  .=.I.o..<AlF.5..
    0x0020:  8018 0631 356f 0000 0101 080a 0000 89df  ...15o..........
    0x0030:  14c7 ba0c 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3832 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.82..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:28:06.410130 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfc3 4000 3f06 b0bb c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6cb7 cd35 0db7  .=.I.o..<Al..5..
    0x0020:  8010 0642 412f 0000 0101 080a 0000 8a76  ...BA/.........v
    0x0030:  14c7 c3e5                                ....
14:28:12.674633 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfc4 4000 3f06 b049 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..I.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6cb7 cd35 0db7  .=.I.o..<Al..5..
    0x0020:  8018 0642 255c 0000 0101 080a 0000 8d79  ...B%\.........y
    0x0030:  14c7 c4fb 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3833 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.83..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:28:13.257680 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfc5 4000 3f06 b0b9 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6d28 cd35 0ebe  .=.I.o..<Am(.5..
    0x0020:  8010 0653 33a5 0000 0101 080a 0000 8e85  ...S3...........
    0x0030:  14c7 cbd7                                ....
14:28:20.223315 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfc6 4000 3f06 b047 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..G.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6d28 cd35 0ebe  .=.I.o..<Am(.5..
    0x0020:  8018 0653 18e9 0000 0101 080a 0000 9186  ...S............
    0x0030:  14c7 cbd7 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ....OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3834 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.84..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:28:21.393424 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfc7 4000 3f06 b0b7 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6d99 cd35 0fc5  .=.I.o..<Am..5..
    0x0020:  8010 0664 26f9 0000 0101 080a 0000 9249  ...d&..........I
    0x0030:  14c7 d336                                ...6
14:28:28.536021 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 113
    0x0000:  4500 00a5 dfc8 4000 3f06 b045 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..E.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6d99 cd35 0fc5  .=.I.o..<Am..5..
    0x0020:  8018 0664 0c3c 0000 0101 080a 0000 954a  ...d.<.........J
    0x0030:  14c7 d336 4f50 5449 4f4e 5320 7274 7370  ...6OPTIONS.rtsp
    0x0040:  3a2f 2f31 3933 2e36 312e 3134 382e 3733  ://193.61.148.73
    0x0050:  3a31 3933 352f 7365 7267 2f61 6e64 726f  :1935/serg/andro
    0x0060:  6964 5f74 6573 7420 5254 5350 2f31 2e30  id_test.RTSP/1.0
    0x0070:  0d0a 4353 6571 3a20 3835 0d0a 436f 6e74  ..CSeq:.85..Cont
    0x0080:  656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 300d 0a53  ent-Length:.0..S
    0x0090:  6573 7369 6f6e 3a20 3332 3136 3938 3736  ession:.32169876
    0x00a0:  350d 0a0d 0a                             5....
14:28:31.395714 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfc9 4000 3f06 b0b5 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6e0a cd35 10cc  .=.I.o..<An..5..
    0x0020:  8010 0674 192a 0000 0101 080a 0000 9672  ...t.*.........r
    0x0030:  14c7 db54                                ...T
14:28:32.849414 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 114
    0x0000:  4500 00a6 dfca 4000 3f06 b042 c13d 9480  E.....@.?..B.=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6e0a cd35 10cc  .=.I.o..<An..5..
    0x0020:  8018 0674 8a65 0000 0101 080a 0000 97b6  ...t.e..........
    0x0030:  14c7 db54 5445 4152 444f 574e 2072 7473  ...TTEARDOWN.rts
    0x0040:  703a 2f2f 3139 332e 3631 2e31 3438 2e37  p://193.61.148.7
    0x0050:  333a 3139 3335 2f73 6572 672f 616e 6472  3:1935/serg/andr
    0x0060:  6f69 645f 7465 7374 2052 5453 502f 312e  oid_test.RTSP/1.
    0x0070:  300d 0a43 5365 713a 2038 360d 0a43 6f6e  0..CSeq:.86..Con
    0x0080:  7465 6e74 2d4c 656e 6774 683a 2030 0d0a  tent-Length:.0..
    0x0090:  5365 7373 696f 6e3a 2033 3231 3639 3837  Session:.3216987
    0x00a0:  3635 0d0a 0d0a                           65....
14:28:32.849434 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfcb 4000 3f06 b0b3 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6e7c cd35 10cc  .=.I.o..<An|.5..
    0x0020:  8011 0674 1773 0000 0101 080a 0000 97b6  ...t.s..........
    0x0030:  14c7 db54                                ...T
14:28:33.889943 IP 193.61.148.128.38255 > 193.61.148.73.1935: tcp 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 dfcc 4000 3f06 b0b2 c13d 9480  E..4..@.?....=..
    0x0010:  c13d 9449 956f 078f 3c41 6e7d cd35 10cd  .=.I.o..<An}.5..
    0x0020:  8010 0674 1259 0000 0101 080a 0000 9899  ...t.Y..........
    0x0030:  14c7 df8a
```

Comment: where is the stream originating from? what hardware exists between the sender and receiver?

Comment: Just edited my post as you added your comment, the streaming device is wireless that connects to a router which is connected to the same wired network as my PC

Comment: What is your operating system? What is your router? What is the streaming device? Enterprise is a company network?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: My OS is Crunchbang (Debian based Linux), my router is a Belkin F5D8235-4 v2, the streaming device is Google Glass. It's a University network so not sure where that falls rules wise but our IT department is unwilling to help as our department doesn't use their managed desktop environment.

Comment: Get a pcap on the server. Look for changes in window size - it sounds like you may be overpowering the server, window size drops to 0 until the server catches up, then window size increases, traffic starts moving again until again, the server gets overpowered and so on.

Comment: I've added the output from the pcap file in the original post.